# Was there anyone else besides Arjuna in Mahabharata who was known as Parthas?

Tags: arjuna, mahabharata

In Mahabharata, at many places the word **Parthas** is used. It means there were many Parthas in addition to Arjuna.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there any clear reference of a person who was known as Partha.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kuntī, the first wife of Pāṇḍu and mother of 3 of the five Pāṇḍavas, was known as Pṛthā at the time of her birth which is described in the Ādi Parva of the Mahabharata. (Note: Pṛthā came to be known as Kuntī after she was adopted by Kuntibhōja) ([source](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01112.htm)):

> There was amongst the Yadavas a chief named Sura. He was the father of Vasudeva. And **he had a daughter called Pritha**, who was unrivalled for beauty on earth. And, O thou of Bharata's race, Sura, always truthful in speech, **gave from friendship this his firstborn daughter unto his childless cousin and friend, the illustrious Kuntibhoja**--the son of his paternal aunt--pursuant to a former promise.

Just as children were referred to by their fathers’ names (eg. sons of Pāṇḍu are called Pāṇḍavas) or family name (eg. descendants of Kuru were called Kauravas), they were referred to even by their mothers’ names. Some examples include:- 
1) Saubhadra - Abhimanyu, son of Subhadrā. [BG 1.6](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/1/6/)
2) Bhauma - Narakāsura, son of Bhūmi. [ŚB 10.59.1](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/10/59/1/)
3) Lord Kārttikēya - Lord Subrahmaṇya, son of Kṛttikās.

By this very same grammatical conjugation in Sanskrit, the sons of Pṛthā (Kuntī) are called as Pārtha (पृथाया अपत्यं पार्थः). **Thus the appellation ‘Pārtha’ is used to refer to the 3 sons of Kuntī viz. Yudhiṣṭhira, Bhīma and Arjuna**. (Note: Nakula and Sahadēva being sons of Mādrī were not generally referred to as Pārtha)

Accordingly, in the references provided in the question,
1) The first line talks about Bhīma lifting the twins and the two Pārthas i.e. Yudhiṣṭhira and Arjuna.
2) The last line talks about Yudhiṣṭhira, being at the forefront of the Pārthas.

[Here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03032.htm) while Draupadi is talking to Yudhiṣṭhira, she addresses him as Pārtha:

> नावमन्ये न गर्हे च धर्मं **पार्थ** कथंचन। ईश्वरं कुत एवाहमवमंस्ये प्रजापतिम् ॥
>
> I do not ever disregard or slander religion, **O son of Pritha**! Why should I disregard God, the lord of all creatures?

[Here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03033.htm) Yudhiṣṭhira addresses Bhīma as Pārtha and also calls Arjuna Pārtha:

> स्वधर्मं प्रतिपद्यस्व जहि शत्रून्समागतान्। धार्तराष्ट्रवनं **पार्थ** मया **पार्थेन** नाशय ॥
>
> Adopt thou, therefore, the virtue of thy order and slay the enemies. Destroy the might of Dhritarashtra's sons, **O son of Pritha**, with my and **Arjuna's** aid

(Note: I am not sure whether Karna has ever been referred to as Partha)